# Deep Linking with react-navigation does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Actually, I'm developing an app on react-native 0.58 with react-navigation 3.1.5, and I can't make my app run properly.

This is my code:

*app-navigation.js*

```
const MainStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Pets: { screen: Pets, path: 'spidersecurity://terque/pets' },
  Notifications: { screen: UserNotifications },
  UpdateUser: { screen: UpdateUser },
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  MainStack: { screen: MainStack, path: '' },
  PetStack: { screen: PetStack }
});

const Main = createSwithNavigator({
  App: { screen: AppStack, path: '' }
});
```

Basically this is my navigation structure. I've setted my `AndroidManifest.xml` to the following:

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="spidersecurity" android:host="terque" />
</intent-filter>
```

And, when I open a link with the address `spidersecurity://terque/pets` this link open the app, but it does not navigate to the specified screen. I don't know if I'm doing something bad, but I've read a lot of pages and blogs with no success.

> **NOTE**: I was verified if 'spidersecurity://terque/pets' is the route matching because I add a `console.log` to my code when getting the Linking

Comment: I think you need to set path to AppStack and Main as well because you nested the screen inside them; and change the path of Pets to 'terque/pets' only; remove the scheme path. *** Suggestions *** try with a simple path first, no-nested until you get the deeplink work. more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html

Comment: How I do set the path to Main? And... AppStack path is defined to: `''`, Where I set the schema if I remove from Pets. Can you provide an example more explicit?

Comment: @TranQuan I've tried with only one deep level and still not working

Answer (score 0):

I've just create an example and confirmed it still working;

Maybe you has tested with `Chrome on android` and Chrome doesn't open the app; In that case, you can read more about it here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Chrome has changed its behavior to `deeplink`

You can check my simple demo; In this case, I just made a very simple `path`
https://github.com/tranquan/rn-deeplink-demo

Comment: If you read my question, I said the link is openning my app already. The link works well, there is not the problem, I need navigate to a specific route when the app is opened by a link

Comment: Hum... strange, I will try to setup the same route as you when having time. But if you have a mock project, it could be better

Comment: In the second intent in the AndroidManifest.xml, you have added a comment like this. <!-- Accept URI begin with "http://kenji/user" --> Is this URL pattern right?

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying the base portion of the URL as a property labeled uriPrefix in the createAppContainer component you export and only have the second portion of the URL `terque/pets` in the 'path'.

Here is an example from their [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/deep-linking.html):

**If your project is created with Expo**

```
const SimpleApp = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({...}));

const prefix = Expo.Linking.makeUrl('/');

const MainApp = () => <SimpleApp uriPrefix={prefix} />;
```

**If your project is created with react-native init**

```
const SimpleApp = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({...}));

const prefix = 'mychat://';

const MainApp = () => <SimpleApp uriPrefix={prefix} />;
```

Try that out and see if it works because that's the way their documentation indicates it should be done.

I've coded it that way in a sample project and when I test using their suggested command line instructions it works properly.

I am still having an issue having the deep link open properly in the actual app I'm building and I've coded it exactly as they suggest so it's possible the issue is being caused somewhere else.

I'd try changing your code to match their documentaiton first and if that doesn't work comment on this post and I'll let you know what solution I find for my app when I figure it out.

Comment: The documentation is not correct. See this issue I filed for the right code to use: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9709.