# How can we redirect to our react-native app when we search the link in browser

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I had implemented deeplinking in react-native both ios and android.

If I click the link `http://mysampleapp.net/user/_id` from Whatsapp or messages etc in android a custom dialogue is opened and we can select you application to open the link, it works fine but if we open the same link in chrome browser it doesn't redirect to my application even the application is installed. How can we do that?

For example, if we search for a product in amazon web in chrome browser and click the product link it automatically redirects and opens the amazon application if the app is installed in you device how can we do that in the react-native application.

I am using `"react-native": "0.61.2"`

Here is the code that I implemented in my manifest.xml file

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysampleapp.net" />
   </intent-filter>
```

Deep linking works fine when I open the link `http://mysampleapp.net/user/_id` from my Whatsapp or any other source, I want to redirect to my application even when I open my link in chrome browser also.

Comment: have you tried this? https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

Comment: yes I had tried that one also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543905/deep-linking-with-react-navigation-does-not-work  this mayhelp

Comment: How about using Dynamic Links from Firebase? They are free and work great, based on my personal experience. You can use the `react-native-firebase` npm package for this.